# NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription does not appear in the list

Tags: swift, dictionary

I want to add a NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to Info.plist , but does not come out in the list

Answer (score 1):

Just try to manually enter the string in your `info.plist`, like editing a plan text.

In the end your list will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean that Xcode is not providing auto completion for that particular key when editing the project info. Which if that is the case, the yes, you will not see auto completion for either in use or always keys. You must manually enter them.

For some reason the Xcode team has not added those into whatever settings file is necessary to provide auto completion in the info lane of the project settings.